# Cancel event bubbling from jquery draggable to click on child element on drag stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a draggable div with a clickable  tag within it:

```
<div id='myDiv'>
      <a id='mylabel' onclick="alert('i am clicked')">some text</a>
</div>
$("#myDiv").draggable({
      stop: function(e){
             //want to cancel the click event on the nested a element 
             //e.preventDefault(); ??
             //e.cancelBubble(); ??
            }
});
```

When I stop dragging, the click event fires, which I don't want.  I tried preventDefault and cancel on the stop drop event but the click event still fires.  Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Sorry I didnt see the structure before. Typically events go bottom up, so if you are trying to drag the `a` element, the click will be fired. The only way to make it work is to put a event.preventDefault on the click which is as good as not putting a click listener on that element.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The trick is to attach a click event to the draggable div like so:

```
$("#myDiv").click(event.stopPropagation());
```

Because dragging the div also invokes a click event, which then propagates to the child a tag, the stop drag event is the wrong thing to stop.  Removing click propagation is the way to go.